# What do the Clojure docs mean by "associative support"?

Tags: clojure

I was reading the Clojure [documentation on datatypes](http://clojure.org/datatypes). Under the list of differences between `deftype` and `defrecord` it states that `defrecord` has "associative support". I'm new to Clojure and was wondering if anyone could clarify this term for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Associative support" means that an object implements [the Associative interface](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.6.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Associative.java). This includes lookup by key, and the ability to create a new object with an additional key/value pair added.

In general, this means that objects created by `defrecord` can be -- for the large part -- treated as if they were standard Clojure maps, whereas when using `deftype`, if you want that functionality you need to implement it yourself.