# Clojure Associative Destructuring by numeric index on List or Seq: Unexpected result

Tags: clojure

Clojure's [Associative Destructuring](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring#_associative_destructuring) allows one to destructure a *vector*, (and maybe a *seq* or *list*) by numeric index.

This pattern is not mentioned at clojure.org so far, but *is* mentioned in the *The Joy of Clojure*, 2nd ed. Michael Fogus, Chris Houser, May 2014, p. 59. There this approach appears in a section called "Associative Destructuring" - wrongly as this index-based destructuring this is just a special case of "Associative Destructuring", which in said book, is called "Destructuring with a map" instead.

Anyway, the results are unexpected (Clojure 1.10.0):

In all cases, extract values at index 0 and 3.

These work as expected:

```
(let [{firstthing 0, lastthing 3} [1 2 3 4]] [firstthing lastthing])
;=> [1 4]

(let [{firstthing 0, lastthing 3} (vec '(1 2 3 4))] [firstthing lastthing])
;=> [1 4]
```

But on a list:

```
(let [{firstthing 0, lastthing 3} '(1 2 3 4)] [firstthing lastthing])
;=> [nil 4]
```

Why is there `nil` at position 0?

Similarly:

```
(let [{firstthing 0, lastthing 3} (seq '(1 2 3 4))] [firstthing lastthing])
;=> [nil 4]
```

But on the other hand:

```
(let [{firstthing 0, lastthing 3} (vec (seq '(1 2 3 4)))] [firstthing lastthing])
;=> [1 4]
```

What's going on here?

**Addendum:**

```
(let [{firstthing 0, lastthing 3} { 1 2 3 4 } ] [firstthing lastthing])
;=> [nil 4]
```

... sounds reasonable as the map to be associatively destructed is actually `{1 2, 3 4}`. So the result of a lookup, not by *position* but by *integer key* (changing the meaning of the expression underneath our feet, so to say) would exactly be `[nil 4]`. Is anything that is not a vector poured into a map first?

```
(let [{firstthing 10, lastthing 30} (seq '(10 2 30 4))] [firstthing lastthing])
;=> [2 4]
```

It certainly looks like it....

```
(let [{firstthing 10, lastthing 30} (seq '(10 2 30 ))] [firstthing lastthing])
; Execution error (IllegalArgumentException) at user/eval367 (REPL:1).
; No value supplied for key: 30
```

Oh yeah.

Comment: It is certainly instructive to dig around in the implementation for the exact source of this behaviour, but simply: lists and seqs are not associative. `(map associative? [{} [] ()])`: `(true true false)`.

Comment: "Is anything that is not a vector poured into a map first?" Not quite - anything that is a seq gets poured into a map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is there nil at position 0?
>
> ```
> (let [{firstthing 0, lastthing 3} '(1 2 3 4)] [firstthing lastthing])
> ;=> [nil 4]
> ```

If you look at the generated code for that `let`:

```clj
user=> (macroexpand '(let [{firstthing 0, lastthing 3} '(1 2 3 4)] [firstthing lastthing]))
(let*
  [map__8012 (quote (1 2 3 4))
   map__8012 (if (clojure.core/seq? map__8012)
               (clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap/create (clojure.core/seq map__8012))
               map__8012)
   firstthing (clojure.core/get map__8012 0)
   lastthing (clojure.core/get map__8012 3)]
  [firstthing lastthing])
```

You see, that in case of a `seq?` it will get converted to a map.  So:

```clj
user=> (def map__8012 (quote (1 2 3 4)))
#'user/map__8012
user=> (clojure.core/seq? map__8012)
true
user=> (clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap/create (clojure.core/seq map__8012))
{1 2, 3 4}
```

Therefor you get `nil` for key `0` and `4` for key `3`.

Comment: Well, that certainly is the answer :-)

Comment: Updated my answer based on this.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that only maps & vectors are associative. Lists and sequences are not associative.  Map destructuring is defined only for associative structures:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(dotest
  (let [mm {:a 1 :b 2}
        vv [1 2 3]
        ll (list 1 2 3)
        sv (seq vv)
        sl (seq ll) ]
    (spyx (associative? mm))
    (spyx (associative? vv))
    (spyx (associative? ll))
    (spyx (associative? sv))
    (spyx (associative? sl)) ) )
```

with result:

```
(associative? mm) => true
(associative? vv) => true
(associative? ll) => false
(associative? sv) => false
(associative? sl) => false
```

Clojure frequently adopts the (rather harsh) attitude of "garbage-in, garbage-out", instead of throwing an exception if you call a function with invalid arguments.

There is even [a warning in ClojureDocs.org](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/get#example-542692d3c026201cdc326fc0)

I would argue that functions should be more bulletproof by default (i.e. check arg values/types), and only supply the stripped-down version as `clojure.core.raw/get` or some similar name.

---

### Update

Based on @cfrick's answer above, we see the genesis of the situation. Since a sequence is not a map, the sequence must be converted into a map before destructuring can occur.  Consequently, `let` assumes you have supplied a sequence of key-value pairs like `[k1 v1  k2 v2  ...]` which should be converted into as map as with:

```
(apply hash-map [k1 v1  k2 v2  ...])
```

If this was not your intent, you should convert the sequence into an associative explicitly by:

```
(zipmap (range) <the-seq>)
```

or, more simply:

```
(vec <the seq>)
```

Or, you could have supplied clojure with the key-value seq it assumed was present:

```
(list 0 1  1 2  2 3  3 4)
```

Note that if your sequence had been of odd length like `(list 1 2 3)` you would have gotten an error during the implicit conversion from seq to map.

Comment: Whenever I hear "associative", I think in mathematical terms: _(a + (b + c)) = ((a + b) + c) == a + b + c_. I then I remember that our profession is sloppy with words and ["Associative support" means that an object implements the Associative interface. This includes lookup by key, and the ability to create a new object with an additional key/value pair added.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633185/what-do-the-clojure-docs-mean-by-associative-support)